# How to store the data of json response using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, location

How can i store the data of https://ipinfo.io/json on my mysql database using php . I am able to view the data but i am quite confused about storing the data on the table visitor_location with the column name as follows ip, city , region , country, loc, org . Till now i am able to fetch the data as here my code :

```js
  <script>
  $.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
  </script>
```

```html
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```

I want to now use this data and store in the mysql database using php

Comment: [MySQLi for Beginners](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and **post what you've tried** with a clear explanation of what **isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I suggest reading [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

**You need to load a jQuery Library.**

```js
$.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {
 $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
 $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
 $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
 /*
 $data=JSON.stringify(response, null, 4);
 $.ajax({
  url: "myAction.php",
  type : "POST",
  data: $data,
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
   // do anythang
  },
  success: function( result ){
   // do anythang
   //console.log(result);
  },
  error: function( xhr ){
   // do anythang
   //console.log(xhr);
  }
 });
 */
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```

> First uncomment the ajax code then enter a valid url then try